# VS2015/ASP.NET MVC 5: Can't set model type on ASPX views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently attempting to convert an older project from VS2013/MVC3 to use VS2015/MVC5, and I've ran into a problem where any old ASPX view (.aspx/.ascx) that sets a strongly-typed model causes a build error.

I've tried with a clean project made from scratch, and the same error occurs, so it makes it fairly simple to reproduce:

1. File > New > Project.
2. Create a new ASP.NET Web Application Project.
3. Select ASP.NET 4.6 Templates > MVC, then click OK.
4. Create an .ascx file in `Views\Home`. (Note that VS2015 doesn't have tooling to create such a file, so you'll have to create a text file and rename it or something.) It should contain:

`<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TestClass>" %>`

Either create a new model class (like I did with `TestClass`), or use one of the pre-built Identity models contained in the project.

5. Add a call to `@Html.Partial("<your_user_control>")` to `Home/Index.cshtml`.
6. Run the project.

This is what I get when I do the above:

[image: Server Error screenshot]

This is the version of VS2015 I'm using:

[image: VS2015 version]

I've tried searching for every possible permutation of search that could uncover this issue, but all I could find is posts confirming that ASPX/ASCX views are indeed supported in VS2015/MVC5, or posts about old versions of MVC.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to ensure a web.config (either your project's base one, or the ones in your base Views folder and the ones for all of your areas) has the following in there somewhere:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages
      validateRequest="false"
      pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
    ...
</system.web>
```

The web.config that come with the default project created in VS2015 does not include this, presumably because they assume (and probably rightly so) greenfield projects won't use the Web Forms view engine.

I found the above by double-checking the [ASP.NET MVC 4->5 upgrade docs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) again.

Answer (score 1):

A generic type declaration written in `C#` like `ViewUserControl<TestClass>` has to go into a `C#` code-behind file. Otherwise, you have to specify a CLR type name:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`1[[MyWebApplication.Models.TestClass, MyWebApplication]]" %>
```

Comment: Did this change at some point? These views that I'm having trouble with all work fine in my VS2013/MVC3 project.

Comment: For example, just opened my VS2013 version of the project and this causes no errors there: `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>" %>`

Comment: If it worked with previous MVC versions (which is not something I was aware of), it may be a good idea to submit the issue to MS as it may be a bug in the latest ASP.NET tools.

Comment: I mean, the ASPX view engine has been supported since ASP.NET MVC v1. I can't find anything saying it was removed.